# Prevent redirection after form submit with a bootstrap validation library

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, formvalidation-plugin

I'm using a [bootsrap validation plugin](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) for form validation. Here is my form submit code. I need to avoid the redirection after form submission.

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
         //ajax call
         return false;
    }
});
```

I referred many tutorials and their suggestion to prevent redirection by adding `return false`. But for this case it doesn't work. Could anyone tell me, what is the wrong in here.

Comment: You read the wrong stuff. The proper way to do this is https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: No he is not. https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Answer (score 0):

You have to preventDefault the event manually, because if everything works, the validator will not prevent the submission.

So try this:

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //Your ajax stuff
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: It breaks ajax call and return "Internal Server Error:500"

Comment: Internal Server Error:500 is a misconfiguration of the page called via ajax. I suppose php? Try activating debug and inspect the ajax call in chrome-tools, or firebug.